Renaming Labels of relationships in Neo4j using parallel processing
I have a lot of relationships in my Neo4j Database for which I have to rename labels. As the number is quite high (close to 13 million), I am processing parallelly for faster execution. I believe my Cypher Query is correct, but a weird error is getting thrown by the system:
Error:
{
  "Invalid input 'CALL': expected\r\n  "!="\r\n  "%"\r\n  "*"\r\n  "+"\r\n  "-"\r\n  "/"\r\n  "::"\r\n  "<"\r\n  "<="\r\n  "<>"\r\n  "="\r\n  "=~"\r\n  ">"\r\n  ">="\r\n  "AND"\r\n  "AS"\r\n  "CONTAINS"\r\n  "ENDS"\r\n  "IN"\r\n  "IS"\r\n  "OR"\r\n  "STARTS"\r\n  "XOR"\r\n  "^"\r\n  "||" (line 3, column 6 (offset: 83))\r\n"     CALL apoc.refactor.rename.type("OLD_LABEL", "NEW_LABEL",r)"\r\n      ^": 1328
} 

I ran this cypher query.
Cypher Query:
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    'MATCH ()-[r:OLD_LABEL]->() RETURN r',
    'WITH r LIMIT 10000
     UNWIND r
     CALL apoc.refactor.rename.type("OLD_LABEL", "NEW_LABEL",r)',
    { batchSize: 10000, parallel: true }
)

Is there something I am missing out or doing it wrong? Also what can be other possible ways to do this job?

simply remove line 3 and 4 since you don't need it when doing iterate.  The apoc iterate will create a batch size of 10k and will process the renaming one at a time.

Some misunderstandings in general
WITH r

doesn't produce a collection, so trying to UNWIND will not work here.
Secondly, UNWIND needs to alias the resulting element, like :
UNWIND batch AS item

However, the most efficient way for your use case is to process per batch and use batchMode = BATCH_SINGLE https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/#_batch_mode_batch_single
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    'MATCH ()-[r:OLD_LABEL]->() RETURN r',
    'CALL apoc.refactor.rename.type("OLD_LABEL", "NEW_LABEL", [x IN $_batch | x.r] )',
    { batchSize: 10000, parallel: true, batchMode: 'BATCH_SINGLE' }
)


Recently, I used this procedure in parallel to round all the scores which took about a minute, so I was trying to process parallelly. Performing operations one batch at a time took much time and didn't utilize all of my resources. Is there any way to also do these operations in parallel?
Here is the query that I used earlier:
MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN r',
WITH r LIMIT 10000
SET r.score = round(r.score, 3)
RETURN count(r)',
[batchSize: 10000, parallel: true}```

My suggestion for this scenario will be as below since the volume is huge
Write a program to do the below in whatever language you use.
Step 1: First return the Ids of relationship using the below query.
MATCH ()-[r:OLD_TYPE]->() WITH r LIMIT 1000 RETURN ID(r) as relationshipId

Step 2 : Stream the above result and put the ids in a list and run the below query.
MATCH ()-[r]->() WHERE ID(r) IN $relIds WITH collect(r) as rel CALL apoc.refactor.rename.type(OLD_TYPE,NEW_TYPE,rel,{batchSize:100,parallel:true})

Repeat the steps 1 and 2 till there are no results from step 1.
